# Solar eclipse question

Tags: solar-eclipse

In a solar eclipse, are we seeing it as the eclipse takes place in real time, or do we see it 8 minutes after it happens because that’s how long the light takes to travel from the sun?

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration! This is a good question, but probably better placed on astronomy.StackExchange - would the moderators consider moving it there? - In one of Jan Meeus's books, there's a chapter discussing similar topics at length (focusing on planet occultations, with some surprising answers!), but I don't have the books near me at the moment.

Comment: @GNiklasch I typically suggest them in flags, so they will surely see it.

Comment: "real time" is a fraught term when light speed and astronomical distances are involved ;-).

Answer (score 5):

The Moon's orbit radius is about 384 400 km [says wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_of_the_Moon). Hence the sunlight eclipsed by the Moon reaches the Earth  1,28 s after passing close by the moon.